# WxWidgets error C2061 (syntax error : 'gstuff')

Tags: c++, syntax, wxwidgets

i'm trying to build a very simple WxWidgets from a photoshop plugin but i get this errors :

```
E:\Program_Files\wxWidgets2.8\include\wx/stream.h(487): warning C4003: number of real parameters not enough for the macro 'freebuffer''
1>E:\Program_Files\wxWidgets2.8\include\wx/stream.h(487): error C2061: esyntax error : 'gStuff' indentifier.
```

i've googled everywhere but i couldn't find anything relevant about these precise errors.

please help me!

Jeff

Comment: Too few context, have you compiled the examples without problems?

Comment: non i didn't compiled the samples as when i try to load the VS projects i have a blank project anyway i found a solution. FreeBuffer is also declared in the SDK of photoshop so i add #undef FreeBuffer before the include of WX and it works now! hope it helps other people. Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just so that this is no longer unanswered!*  The following comments include the answer that was found.

Too few context, have you compiled the examples without problems? – notNullGothik Jul 18 at 16:14

non i didn't compiled the samples as when i try to load the VS projects i have a blank project anyway i found a solution. FreeBuffer is also declared in the SDK of photoshop so i add #undef FreeBuffer before the include of WX and it works now! hope it helps other people. Jeff – IonOne Jul 19 at 11:55